# TempData Persisting indefinitely on one page, not on another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I have an action called `Messages` which has two forms.

The first form posts to `SendMessage` and the second posts to `MessagesDelete`. Both pages return a `ReturnToAction` of the Messages view, and both use TempData to return feedback data (message sent, messages deleted etc) indicating that an action has occured.

`MessagesDelete` works fine, returning the TempData just the first time and then removing it in future requests. `SendMessage` on the other hand, persists the TempData endlessly.

Here's some simplified code.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Messages(int? id, string message)
    {
        MessagesModel model = new MessagesModel();
        // build model data here
        return View(model);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MessagesDelete(int[] selectedObjects, int? id)
    {
        // delete objects
        TempData["MessagesDeleted"] = selectedObjects.Count() + " deleted";
        return RedirectToAction("Messages", new { id = id });
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(SendMessageModel model)
    {
        // send my message
        TempData["MessageSent"] = "message sent!";
        return RedirectToAction(model.action, new { id = model.action_id } ); 
    }
```

The only difference I can see is that `MessagesDelete` is send the id directly, whereas SendMessage has it as a property within the model.

Comment: In your SendMessage...action method....to which actionmethod is it redirecting to?... that is at..."return RedirectToAction(model.action, new { id = model.action_id } );"...can you post the code of that action method as well...that might help us more...

Comment: I might suggest trying renaming the action property of your  SendMessageModel class.  I had a class with this name for a property and I remember it causing a problem for me with model binding.  Although I can't remember exactly what it was, wish I'd documented it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement one-off messages to users based on actions they take. In this situation, I would rathe architect your solution a little bit differently than take on the headache that is using `TempData` and it's unreliability.

Here's what I would do:

1) Create a base ViewModel for all ViewModels expecting to show one-off messages.

```
public class OneOffMessageViewModelBase
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

2) Then, add a OnResultExecutingFilter to pull data from session to store in the view model (or, add an override to your base controller):

```
public class AllowOneOffMessagingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

         var actionResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

         if(actionResult != null)
         {
              var viewModel = actionResult.ViewData.Model as OneOffMessageViewModelBase;

              if(viewModel != null)
              {
                   if(Session["OneOffMessage"] != null)
                   {
                       viewModel.Message = Session["OneOffMessage"];
                       Session["OneOffMessage"] = null;
                   }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

3) Then, you simply need to assign to that session variable, and you can be assured that the next view (and not partial view) will assign the one off message to the view model, and then the data will be deleted.

Comment: This does seem like a cleaner solution, although something in point 3 gave me a thought. the TempData["MessageSent"] is being rendered in a partial view which is called by the main Messages view. Could that be a problem?

Comment: If it's a specific Partial View, then you need to just move this code into your action method for that partial view instead of in the OnResultExecuting.

Comment: I actually had planned to do something like this, but I was converting TempData into ViewData and setting the TempData to null. I was hoping there was a really neat way. Thanks